# Using one WP_Query object within the loop of another WP_Query object

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm creating two different WP_Query objects, one for each of two different post types I'm using. In creating my output, I'd like to loop through one of the objects, and at the same time loop through the other object as well, so I can output pieces of them together. Here's an example of what I'd like to accomplish:

```
$rotator_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'rotator',
    );

$rotator = new WP_Query($rotator_args);

$numrotators = $rotator->post_count; 

$testimonial_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonial',
    'posts_per_page' => $numrotators,
    );

$testimonial = new WP_Query($testimonial_args);

while ( $rotator->have_posts() ) : 
    $rotator->the_post(); //setup the rotator posts
    $testimonial->the_post(); //this breaks things, understandably
    $rotator_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($rotator->ID, 'large');
    $testimonial_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($testimonial->ID, 'large');
    $return .= '<div>' . $rotator_image . '</div>';
    $return .= '<div>' . $testimonial_image . '</div>';
endwhile;
return $return;
```

However, that doesn't work. Taking out `$testimonial->the_post();` (and the associated `$testimonial` related code) fixes things.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're aiming for here, functionality-wise. If you're trying to associate posts, why not use scribu's posts2posts plugin? http://scribu.net/wordpress/posts-to-posts

Comment: Nope, not trying to associate them.

Answer (score 3):

Go through each loop, storing the post object in an array. Then at the end combine them. (This is completely untested)

https://gist.github.com/1762204

Comment: Bill's got the right end of the stick on this one, methinks. Though it does seem a tad un-optimized.

Comment: At first glance this looks perfect. @ZaMoose, is there anything in particular that seems un-optimized? (asking so I can work on speeding it up if necessary/possible).

Comment: This doesn't allow for using any functions that don't take a post ID (or other WP_Query property) as an argument, does it? If not, any suggestions on a way to implement something that does allow for using e.g. `get_the_content()`?

Comment: You're essentially parsing through two arrays of objects and then doing the same thing over again -- you're duplicating your effort to avoid $post-related clobberings. I may have to give this some thought.

Comment: Right before the loop put `print_r( $rotator_items[0] );` to see all the data you have. For instance, for the content use `$rotator_items[0]->post_content`

Comment: After testing this, it seems the last while loop (`while ($loop_counter < $count)`) is causing a problem - the page never finishes loading, and Apache jumps up to using ~90% of my cpu (working locally). Removing lines 27 and 32 of the Gist eliminate that, but obviously then you're only accessing the first item in the array(s). Any insight is welcome.

Comment: Have you checked out the updated gist I left over on github? https://gist.github.com/1764801

Comment: @ZaMoose - basically what you're suggesting is only store one object in an array, and then just use a normal loop for the second one (initializing it with e.g. $testimonial->the_post(), and use the array created for $rotator when necessary to access stuff from that object?

Comment: Pretty much, yup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can merge the two loops together, since there isn't anything to keep them separate from a data standpoint. Are you trying to add data from a testimonial into the rotator as it goes?

Comment: Yes, trying to get data from the testimonial inside the rotator pane (actually using <li>s instead of <div>s, but I changed that to simplify things here).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** [Bill's refactor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41550/12884) is much better than my duct tape
**Edit:** Additionally, my edit will stick with the same testimonial which wasn't even the desired outcome. Again: please see [Bill's refactor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41550/12884)

The trouble you're having is with $post. Every time you fire the_post() $post has the applicable data. I would suggest something like the following:

```
global $post;

$rotator_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'rotator',
    );

$rotator = new WP_Query($rotator_args);

$numrotators = $rotator->post_count; 

$testimonial_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonial',
    'posts_per_page' => $numrotators,
    );

$testimonial = new WP_Query($testimonial_args);
if( $testimonial->have_posts() )
{
    $testimonial->the_post();
    $my_testimonial = $post;
}

while ( $rotator->have_posts() ) : 
    $rotator->the_post(); //setup the rotator posts
    $rotator_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($rotator->ID, 'large');
    $testimonial_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($my_testimonial->ID, 'large');
    $return .= '<div>' . $rotator_image . '</div>';
    $return .= '<div>' . $testimonial_image . '</div>';
endwhile;
return $return;
```

Comment: This won't work. It will continually return a single testimonial.

Comment: You're totally right, I didn't realize he was trying to grab a new one in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some piece of data that connects $rotator to $testimonial? If not then I don't see what the point is…you just have two disparate loops.

Comment: Right, but I want them to run together, essentially, so that I can output information from them in a connected fashion Any one post in the rotator post type is not, however, connected to any one post in the testimonial post type.